# Can't log in with X11 on GNOME

Tags: linux, xorg, gnome, manjaro

I can't connect to Gnome Desktop with X11. When I log in, it kicks me back to login screen.

**Manjaro Linux - rolling, Gnome 43.5**

Actually, it works on Wayland.

**Xorg.0.log**

```
[  1538.652] (--) Log file renamed from "/home/guillew/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.pid-15635.log" to "/home/guillew/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log"
[  1538.652] 
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.8
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1538.652] Current Operating System: Linux Manjaro 6.1.26-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Apr 26 22:07:35 UTC 2023 x86_64
[  1538.652] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.1-x86_64 root=UUID=95ca9132-1f5f-4dc3-b775-f899eef1df74 rw quiet splash apparmor=1 security=apparmor udev.log_priority=3
[  1538.652]  
[  1538.652] Current version of pixman: 0.42.2
[  1538.652]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1538.652] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1538.652] (==) Log file: "/home/guillew/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu May 18 12:35:55 2023
[  1538.653] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1538.653] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1538.653] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  1538.653] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  1538.653] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  1538.653] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1538.653] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[  1538.653] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[  1538.653] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  1538.653] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1538.653] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1538.653] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  1538.653] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[  1538.653] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  1538.653] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/misc" does not exist.
[  1538.653]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1538.653] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF" does not exist.
[  1538.653]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1538.653] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[  1538.653]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1538.653] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi" does not exist.
[  1538.653]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1538.653] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi" does not exist.
[  1538.653]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1538.653] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF
[  1538.653] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1538.653] (**) Extension "Composite" is enabled
[  1538.653] (**) Extension "RENDER" is enabled
[  1538.654] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  1538.654] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1538.654]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1538.654]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[  1538.654]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[  1538.654]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  1538.654] (++) using VT number 2

[  1538.655] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_311
[  1538.655] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  1538.655] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:07:00.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:00.0/drm/card0
[  1538.655] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 14 paused 0
[  1538.658] (--) PCI:*(9@0:0:0) 1002:73ff:1462:5020 rev 193, Mem @ 0x7c00000000/8589934592, 0x7e00000000/268435456, 0xfca00000/1048576, I/O @ 0x0000e000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  1538.658] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[  1538.658] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1538.658] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1538.659] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1538.659]    compiled for 1.21.1.8, module version = 1.0.0
[  1538.659]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  1538.659] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  1538.659] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  1538.659] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1538.659]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 2.6.0
[  1538.659]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1538.659]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[  1538.659] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  1538.659] xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)
[  1538.659] vesa: Refusing to run, Framebuffer or dri device present
[  1538.659] vesa: Refusing to run, Framebuffer or dri device present
[  1538.659] (EE) No devices detected.
[  1538.659] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  1538.659] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[  1538.659] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  1538.659] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/guillew/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  1538.659] (EE) 
[  1538.707] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

What I tried :

- No extensions installed.
- Found on posts that `(WW) Open ACPI failed` is not a problem here, so I can ignore it for now.
- Found lots of posts about `xf86EnableIO: failed to enable` but no one helps me, or I probably miss something.

Thanks you for help or tips o/

## Update 1:

remove all `xf86-video-*` packages

```
[   557.725] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   557.726] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[   557.726] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[   557.726] (EE) No drivers available.
[   557.726] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   557.726] (EE) no screens found(EE)
```

## Update 2: vesa.conf

Here's the `/etc/X11/mhwd.d/vesa.conf` file. When removed, I can now log in Gnome X11 session.

```
##
## Generated by mhwd - Manjaro Hardware Detection
##
 
 
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Device0"
    Driver      "vesa"
    BusID       "PCI:9:0:0"
    Option      "DRI"    "true"
EndSection
 
 
Section "DRI"
        Group  "video"
        Mode   0666
EndSection
 
 
Section "Extensions"
    Option "Composite" "Enable"
    Option "RENDER"    "Enable"
EndSection
 
 
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier          "Keyboard Defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard        "yes"
    Option              "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection
```

Comment: Try ditching `xf86-video-vesa` with `pacman`.

Comment: Reinstall this package doesn't help. Still digging.

Comment: No one asked you to reinstall. I meant it when I said `ditch`. (And if it still doesn't work after you actually ditched it, you may want to share an updated version of log.)

Comment: Btw, to save you sometime, you should really ditch all xf86-video-* packages except maybe the amdgpu one (even that one is in some sense optional).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `ditch all xf86-video-* packages`, so I remove them, and got error in the Updated logs. If I keep only `xf86-video-vesa` or `xf86-video-amdgpu`, The error in first log come back.

Comment: Do you have any conf files in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` (or `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`) that are not shipped by the distro? (i.e., when `pacman -Qo` on them it gives you an "error" that no package owns them)

Comment: Good hint ! I remove `/etc/X11/mhwd.d/vesa.conf` file and I can now login with Gnome X11. Thanks a lot. You can suggest an Answer so I can give you bounty. I'll update my OP with the content of this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advices from [Tom Yan](https://superuser.com/users/554702/tom-yan), remove misconfigured config file here
`/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`
or here
`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`.

This solved the issue for me, I removed this file `/etc/X11/mhwd.d/vesa.conf` and all good after that.